# AngularJS input[tel]

Tags: html, angularjs

As far as I'm concerned, AngularJS do not respond to input[tel].

1. There's no online documentation about it.
2. It's not working, when connecting through ng-model ng-value or even value.

--

How to put in a default value in such field? Anyone got it to work?

Comment: Can you post a plunk or fiddle showing the problem?  Here's a plunk showing that it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/ppHTYpvW9Lwfq3BmjCBO?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine in Angular.

```
<input type="tel" ng-model="item.tel">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.item = {
  tel: "1 (555) 555-5555"
}
```

Your problem may be browser support, however browsers that don't support the tel input will default to text.